# CSV to JSON output only if all values are present in CSV

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a concatenated CSV file that I am attempting to output into JSON format. How should I go about implementing the logic that the CSV file only get converted to a JSON object all fields have a value ?

```
import glob , os
import pandas as pd
import json
import csv



with open('some.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvfile, \
     open('output.json', 'w') as jsonfile:

    for row in csv.DictReader(csvfile):
        restructured = {
            'STATION_CODE': row['STORE_CODE'],
            'id': row['ARTICLE_ID'],
            'name': row['ITEM_NAME'],
            'data':
              {
            # fieldname: value for (fieldname, value) in row.items()
                    'STORE_CODE': row['STORE_CODE'],
                    'ARTICLE_ID': row['ARTICLE_ID'],
                    'ITEM_NAME': row['ITEM_NAME'],
                    'BARCODE': row['BARCODE'],
                    'SALE_PRICE': row['SALE_PRICE'],
                    'LIST_PRICE': row['LIST_PRICE'],
                    'UNIT_PRICE': row['UNIT_PRICE'],
                  }
        }
        json.dump(restructured, jsonfile, indent=4)
        jsonfile.write('\n')
```

Currently this will provide all values from the CSV file into the JSON output, which is unintended behavior. Any inputs on how to correct this ?

Comment: To be clear, if `CSV` file has `empty value` on `any row`; JSON file should `not be outputted at all`  OR  if `CSV` row has any empty value; `only those rows` should no be `outputted to the JSON file`?

Comment: @ChathurangaK if the CSV row has an an empty value only those rows should not be outputted to the JSON file. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 0):

First I loop through all the elements of `CSV` and add it to a `JSON array`. If any row element `value is empty`, that row will be `ignored`. Once I have the all rows in the `JSON array`, I will output it to the `JSON` file

```
import json
import csv

csvjsonarr = []

with open('some.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvfile :

    for row in csv.DictReader(csvfile):
        
        hasemptyvalues = False

        for rowidx in row :
            if row[rowidx] == "" :
                hasemptyvalues = True
                break

        if hasemptyvalues == True :
            continue

        restructured = {
            'STATION_CODE': row['STORE_CODE'],
            'id': row['ARTICLE_ID'],
            'name': row['ITEM_NAME'],
            'data': {
                'STORE_CODE': row['STORE_CODE'],
                'ARTICLE_ID': row['ARTICLE_ID'],
                'ITEM_NAME': row['ITEM_NAME'],
                'BARCODE': row['BARCODE'],
                'SALE_PRICE': row['SALE_PRICE'],
                'LIST_PRICE': row['LIST_PRICE'],
                'UNIT_PRICE': row['UNIT_PRICE'],
            }
        }
        csvjsonarr.append(restructured)
        
if len(csvjsonarr) > 0 :
    with open('output.json', 'w') as jsonfile :
        json.dump(csvjsonarr, jsonfile, indent=4)
```